# How to move focus window without closing popup window in WPF C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to move focus from popup window to parent window without closing popup window. For example Find and replace dialog-box behavior in Excel.

how to achieve this in WPF C# coding.

Comment: Make a modeless dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Call .Show() instead of .ShowDialog() when you displaying your popup. If you want to keep it on top - set popup window 'TopMost' property to true.

Comment: How to set Focus to popup window when popup opened?

Comment: call Activate() on it.